# usb port sniffing and usb port trigger when data captured

Tags: usb, sniffing

I want to sniff a usb port in Windows and when specific data have been captured I want to send them through another usb port on the same computer. I am able to make the capture with Wireshark and usbcap but I want to do this on real time. Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

when you have the filtered data sending it seem just as simple as to receive it but it doesn't.
USB is not a simple i/o device
ill redirect you to read this answer  :[here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88990787-a69d-4dab-962a-de94b1ea5000/how-to-send-a-byte-to-usb?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: Please edit your answer to illustrate what the answer covers as answers should be able to live without relying on external sources.  Help us prevent link rot and produce quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I landed on was to use Autohotkey and a script [AHKHID](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/38015-ahkhid-an-ahk-implementation-of-the-hid-functions/).

It only works to listen to the selected USB device, and have no means to send data to a USB device.

But it solved my problem: Jabra headset not supporting my softphone.